# Can connect to my OpenLDAP server locally but not externally

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have a problem with my OpenLDAP server. I can't connect to it externally from client, it only works locally. My OpenLDAP server is running on a Raspberry Pi with Rasbian as the OS.

When I run this ldapsearch from a client:

```
$ ldapsearch -h ldap://ldap.fast.com -p 389 -D "dc=fast,dc=com" -x -W
```

I get: `ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)`

But when do it locally in the raspberry everything works fine.

I do not have iptables configured:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) 
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain L (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain fail2ban-ssh (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

This is my `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` file:

```
# LDAP Defaults


# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.

BASE     dc=fast,dc=com
URI ldap://ldap.fast.com ldap://ldap.fast.com:666

#SIZELIMIT  12
#TIMELIMIT  15
#DEREF      never

# TLS certificates (needed for GnuTLS)
TLS_CACERT  /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

TLSCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:+TLSv1:!SSLv2:+SSLv3
TLSCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ldap-cert.pem
TLSCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ldap-cert.pem
TLSCertificateKeyFile /etc/ldap/ldap-ssl.pem
TLSVerifyClient demand
```

My FQDN is: **ldap.fast.com**

My domain is: **fast.com**

The server is listeing to both ports (389 and 636), output from `ss -tuln | grep -E '389|636'`:

```
tcp    LISTEN     0      128                    *:636                   *:*

tcp    LISTEN     0      128                    *:389                   *:*
```

Telnetting into port 389 and 636 gives me this:

```
Trying 192.168.1.5...
Connected to ldap.fast.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to ping to ldap.fast.com from the client & also what is the result of telnetting to that port?.

Comment: @StackPlayer Yes both, ping and telnet works fine. I can telnet to both port 389 and 636.

Comment: Ok. You can try to run the command in Verbose more -v & also check the LDAP server log to see if it says any client specific error.

Comment: Is ldap.fast.com actually resolvable externally? I can't resolve it. Or are you running a vpn solution and clients use internal DNS?

Answer (score 1):

"-h" is used for hostnames, "-H" is used for URIs.  Try doing your query as:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://ldap.fast.com:389 -D "dc=fast,dc=com" -x -W
```

(the "-p" is not used with "-H", instead include the port if needed in the URI)